# I am trying to make a code editor, but nothing appears in the result box

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to add a code editor to my website, but nothing is appearing in the result box.

I tried to use .innerHTML to extract the code, and put it in the result box, but nothing appeared.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<textarea id='codeBox'>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>

      </body>
    </html>
</textarea>
<div id='result'></div>
<button onclick='run()' style='text-align: center;'>Run</button>
<style>
body {
display: grid;
grid-columns: 50% 50%;
}

#codeBox {
grid-column: 1;
height: 500px;
overflow: scroll;
}

#result {
grid-column: 2;
height: 500px;
overflow: scroll;
border: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>
<script>
let codeBox = document.getElementById('codeBox').innerHTML;
let result = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
function run() {
result.innerHTML = codeBox.innerHTML;
};
</script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Use `value` of textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the textarea value, and you should read the value every time you click run, and not only when loading the page.

```js
function run() {
  result.innerHTML = document.getElementById('codeBox').value;
};
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

#codeBox {
  grid-column: 1;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#result {
  grid-column: 2;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='codeBox'>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
      It works!
      </body>
    </html>
</textarea>
<div id='result'></div>
<button onclick='run()' style='text-align: center;'>Run</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Takeoff innerhtml to below variable and execute

```
let codeBox = document.getElementById('codeBox').innerHTML;
let result = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
```

### Modified code

```
    <script>
    let codeBox = document.getElementById('codeBox');
    let result = document.getElementById('result');
    function run() {
    result.innerHTML = codeBox.innerHTML;
    };
   </script>
```

### Link

https://code.sololearn.com/Ws6DW8hp6XS5